# How can i set the bluetooth pin number in linux C/C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, api, bluetooth

Hi my name is yunsu lee from south korea

Because i have a just little bit english skill, i hope to your understanding about my awkward english

I have a one question.

I can not find a API of setting bluetooth pin number in bluez, when set a bluetooth connection in linux C/C++ environment

Comment: Hi Yunsu, Welcome. Your English is good. Try to add more descriptive information about your problem. What flavor of Linux, what type of API/SDK etc.,

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the late reply too. Already i solve this problem. if occured another problem, i will descript detailed information as you have said. Happy New Year~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pins are handled by an Agent. If you want to implement your own agent read the doc in  bluez/doc/agent-api.txt. In summary:

To register your agent:

void RegisterAgent(object agent, string capability)

Your agent object will need to implement some/all of the agent callbacks. For example:

string RequestPinCode(object device)

This method gets called when the service daemon
    needs to get the passkey for an authentication

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the late reply too. I use RequestPinCode method, and then i solve my problem. Happy New Year~!